# How to make an email flyer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, html, marketing

I have a client and he's been wanting me to create an e-flyer for him. When I first read it, I wasn't paying much attention to the details so I ended up thinking he just wanted a flyer for printing. So when I checked again cause I've been wanting to work on it, I realized that it's an e-flyer and I have no idea how to do this. I've read articles and discussions here but I can't seem to find the answer.

So here's the approach that I've been thinking. Please tell me if it's correct or not and the disadvantages of using this approach and a better way of doing it.

- Use Photoshop to design the header, footer, body/background
- Then use divs or tables to have it working (my client wants a video on the e-flyer as well)

Also, I want to know what would be the best width for an e-flyer and can I use CSS for the layout and fonts?

Thanks!

Comment: e-flyer? I have no idea what it is. I can see two alternatives. 1. a "designed" email. 2. a file (i.e. a pdf). You should ask the client, and maybe pay a bit more attention?

Comment: here are some examples:

http://www.your-marketing-solution.com/email_flyer_samples.html

http://www.thomstanton.com/email-marketing.htm

Comment: Right. So it is simply a graphic document? Then I do not understand the question? You design it. Does not seem to have anything to do with code.

Comment: I would think its just an email using HTML to mark up formatting. I think your best bet would be to design it as you would a single page website.

Comment: @boblet As I have said, the client wants a video in it as well.

Comment: Yes, you _could_ do that with pdf.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris, Yeah. That's what I've been thinking. I'm just not so sure about it cause I also have to think of one more thing. Ensuring that it won't go into the spam folder.

Comment: @boblet, pdf? So it'll be like a file attached in the email and people won't see it unless they download it?

Comment: @CheeseCake There's no way for you to control what others have set for their spam folders. So if other emails from your client get sent to spam folders, your email will, too.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris, True. I've just done some research and I've read articles about it like this one. http://www.mailup.com/spam-words-to-avoid.htm

Comment: If you have any other comments, you should take them into the chat. The mods frown on extensive conversations in the questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"e-flier" is a bit of a nonsense term. It means nothing since electronic delivery can be done in so many various ways.

**If the client wants a file** he can email to perspective people when requested, then a PDF is appropriate. You can embed video, audio, and other interactive elements in a PDF. How you generate the PDF really depends upon what software you have available. Adobe InDesign has *many* features designed to create interactive PDFs.

**If the client wants a "landing page"**, single web page, or link he can direct people to then standard HTML/CSS markup is appropriate. Basically, it's just a web page. Create it how you would create any other web page.

**If the client wants an email** to be sent out to perspective people, then using HTML tables is more appropriate. Yes I typed "tables". Email clients are still well behind many browsers. If you want email clients to see things properly using tables is still the best method. You should avoid all background images (some email providers strip them away like GMail) and make *all your CSS inline* rather than external or referenced in the header. In this case, I can not state emphatically enough that a **video in the email is a very poor idea**. You should try with all your might to discourage this. It will raise the spam rating of the email considerably. High spam level marks will get the client blacklisted from *many* email services. Once blacklisted, it can take quite some effort to get white listed again. There are some helpful services for email HTML files such as [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) which will move styles to inline and other things in preparation for emailing.

[Here is a link](http://www.melon.com.au/melon-stork) to check your email for spam ratings.

And [here is a link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to show what CSS is supported in various email clients.

Comment: My client wants an email to be sent out but can I use divs instead of tables? I'm sorry I'm really bad at coding.

Comment: Generally it's better to use tables for emails. Many email clients do not support divs well and still work best with mid-90's HTML structures. Outlook is notorious for being poor with rendering xHTML or HTML5 and Outlook is a very popular email client.